# android app doesnt crash after installiation

Tags: java, android

So I have very weird problem with android app that I developed that I really do not understand how to address.
Description of the problem: When I run the app in my emulator(and many other emulators) the app works perfectly, but when I list it on Google Play and some user download the app, it automatically crashes. so I just wonder if my androidmainfest is properly written.
*the program written in esclipse, java, android.

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="1.5" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >      
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
                <activity
            android:name="com.example.SurfaceExampleView"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.start" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.RulesGame"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.rules" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <activity
            android:name="com.example.PolicyGame"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.policy" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <activity
            android:name="com.example.RevenueGame"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.revenue" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ShopGame"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.shop" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
    </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Does it crash for all Play Store users? Maybe on a specific Android version only? Have you tried to download it from Play yourself? Have you actually tried the release APK before publishing it? It may behave differently than the debug version. Anyway, it is unlikely the problem is caused by the manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have posted only your manifest and not the logs. My guesses based on that is the problem may be within your `package` declaration, rest everything seems fine.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.app".....
```

The package should be unique and its like what we call package in java world. You have declared it as `com.app` whereas your app is using `com.example....` package. Also `com.app` maybe used by other app.The package name defines your application's identity.

Once you publish your application, you cannot change the package name. As the package name defines your application's identity, so if you change it, then it is considered to be a different application and users of the previous version cannot update to the new version. So you may have to upload another app with different package name.

Try getting logs(use [crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/)) for your crash and we can look into it for the root cause.

Comment: Not in java code, I am talking about the manifest. Its the one I have copied the in my answer. `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.app"`<----Problem here

Comment: I just wonder, Can i send you a link to my app in google play. and tell me if it crashes or no. because if it does many users will not even report it. so it is why

Comment: Ya that would work...or you can just connect your mobile to the tools meanwhile install the app from market...you will get at least get some minimal log...

Comment: so here is the link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.bubbledream&hl=en

Comment: I highly appreciate your help, as I said Im pretty experienced with android and java, I just dont understand why it crashes. but thank you so much Ranjith